# How to keep fixed the size of a container with html5, css3 and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div id="rtgbo"></div>                  
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#rtgbo').prepend('<p>' + data.message + '</p>');
```

Data is properly appending in my html id (from `data.message`), but causes the size of my site to be increased.

I need that keep fixed the size of my site.

Please help!

Comment: width=100px;  for the div  ? would that work? its hard to tell without looking at your website

Comment: It's a web application and use bootstrap. It's a row with col s9 and col s3, well the data is shown in the s3 from the javascript code JS. When the data is appending the size of my site is incremented and I wanto to keep the s3 size.

Comment: just set the font to display:inline-block; and set a font size to what ever you want.......... this should fix the issue

Comment: And the height? data is appending constantly i don't want to use the scroll i want to keep fixed.

Comment: what about overflow? try http://jsfiddle.net/iboylmz/w93vtLkf/

Comment: yeah, i don't want to scroll down.

Comment: use your developer tool and check what is the issue.......